# Subsonic Active Record Execute Direct SQL

Tags: .net, subsonic3, subsonic-active-record

How can I execute direct/raw SQL through subsonic 3.0 when using the Active Record pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it http://subsonicproject.com/docs/CodingHorror